# Como quitar alert al momento de presionar una tecla

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy presentando un problema con un `alert` de validación de correo que se mostrara en caso de que el mensaje que se ingrese no corresponda a un correo valido, quisiera que al momento de presionar cualquier tecla desaparezca el `alert`

El siguiente es un pequeño snippet que pueden tomar como referencia de lo que hablo.

```js
function EnviarInformacion() {
  var Contacto = $("#Contacto").val();
  const alerta = document.getElementById("alert");
  // Eliminar clase antes de validar
  alerta.classList.remove("show")
  if (/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i.test(Contacto)) {
    //Codigo de validacion aquí
  } else {
    // Agregar clase cuando es un correo inválido
    alerta.classList.add("show")
  }
}
```

```css
.alert {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  max-height: 0;
  /* Comienza con altura en cero */
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.alert-danger {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 150px;
  /* Altura adaptable a contenido */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
                                    <div class=" col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                        <br /><br />
                                        <p>
                                            <span class="ContenidoContactoMensaje">Ingresa tu correo
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />

                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 alinearDerecha">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 row2">

                                            <input type="email" name="Contacto" id="Contacto" value="" size="50" class="form-control" />
                                            <div id="alert" class="alert alert-danger" style="font-family: 'Lettera Text Std';">Favor de ingresar una cuenta de correo válida.</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 row2">
                                            <button class="EnviarContactoDetalleProducto btn-lg" onclick="EnviarInformacion(1,1)"> Enviar</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
```

Lo anterior es con el objetivo de que al momento de que la persona escribió un texto cualquier pues no le permita enviar y al hacerlo se genere el `alert` pero si la persona se dio cuenta de que es necesario un correo valido pues va a eliminar lo que escribió y va escribir nuevamente uno totalmente valido. Espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro con mi pregunta.

**Actualización:**

Agrego código actual en donde incluyo validaciones pero no vi el caso necesario de agregarlo a mi pregunta inicial, adicional a este código agrego al final la validación que me aportan en una de las respuestas.

```
function EnviarInformacion(Categoria, Producto) {
    var Nombre_Producto = "";
    var Nombre_Categoria = "";
    let Contacto = $("#Contacto").val();
    $("#alert").removeClass("show");
    if (/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i.test(Contacto)) {
        if (Categoria == 1) {
            Nombre_Categoria = "Categoria 1";
            if (Producto == 1) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Produc 1";
            }
            if (Producto == 2) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Produc 2";
            }
            if (Producto == 3) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Produc 3";
            }
            if (Producto == 4) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Produc 4";
            }
            if (Producto == 5) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Produc 5";
            }
            if (Producto == 6) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Produc 6";
            }
            if (Producto == 7) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Produc 7";
            }
            if (Producto == 8) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Produc 8";
            }
        } else if(Categoria == 2) {
            Nombre_Categoria = "Categoria 2";

            if (Producto == 1) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Prod 1";
            }
            if (Producto == 2) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Prod 2";
            }
            if (Producto == 3) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Prod 3";
            }
            if (Producto == 4) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Produ 4";
            }
        } else {
            Nombre_Categoria = "Categoria 3";
            if (Producto == 1) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Prod 1";
            }
            if (Producto == 2) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Prod 2";
            }
            if (Producto == 3) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Prod 3";
            }
            if (Producto == 4) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Prod 4";
            }
            if (Producto == 5) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Prod 5";
            }
            if (Producto == 6) {
                Nombre_Producto = "Prod 6";
            }
        }
        if (Nombre_Producto != "" && Contacto!="") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",

                url: "Test.php",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    Categoria: Categoria,
                    Nombre_Categoria: Nombre_Categoria,
                    Nombre_Producto: Nombre_Producto,
                    Contacto: Contacto

                }),
                dataType: 'JSON',
                method: 'post',
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    data = $.parseJSON(result.d)
               
                    if (data.length) {

                        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var Resultado = data[i]['Resultado'];
                        }
                        alert("Muestra mensaje si se envia.")
                        window.location.reload(); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        $("#alert").addClass("show");
    }
}

// Escuchar cambios en campo
$('#Contacto').on('input', function () {
    $("#alert").removeClass("show");
});
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el HTML que corresponde a la actualización.

Comment: @Triby Por favor valida nuevamente en mi pregunta, actualice mi HTML correspondiente a la ultima actualización.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo necesitas agregar una función para escuchar cambios en el campo, el evento `input` podría ser suficiente. Por cierto, cambié la forma de agregar y eliminar clases, usando la API de jQuery porque no tiene sentido mezclar con Javascript puro.

```js
function EnviarInformacion(Categoria, Producto) {
    // Evitar envío de formulario
    event.preventDefault();
    
    let Nombre_Producto = "";
    let Nombre_Categoria = "";
    let Contacto = $("#Contacto").val();
    $("#alert").removeClass("show");
    if (/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i.test(Contacto)) {
        // Simplificar nombre de categoría y producto
        if(Categoria >= 1 && Categoria <= 3) {
            Nombre_Categoria = 'Categoría ' + Categoria;
            if(
                (Categoria == 1 && Producto >= 1 && Producto <= 8)
                || (Categoria == 2 && Producto >= 1 && Producto <= 4)
                (Categoria == 3 && Producto >= 1 && Producto <= 6)
            ) {
                Nombre_Producto = 'Prod ' + Producto;
            }
        }

        if (Nombre_Producto != "" && Contacto!="") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",

                url: "Test.php",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    Categoria: Categoria,
                    Nombre_Categoria: Nombre_Categoria,
                    Nombre_Producto: Nombre_Producto,
                    Contacto: Contacto

                }),
                dataType: 'JSON',
                method: 'post',
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    data = $.parseJSON(result.d)
               
                    if (data.length) {

                        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var Resultado = data[i]['Resultado'];
                        }
                        alert("Muestra mensaje si se envia.")
                        window.location.reload(); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        $("#alert").addClass("show");
    }
}

// Escuchar cambios en campo
$('#Contacto').on('input', function () {
    $("#alert").removeClass("show");
});
```

```css
.alert {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    max-height:0; /* Comienza con altura en cero */
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.alert-danger {
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 150px; /* Altura adaptable a contenido */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
                                    <div class=" col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                        <br /><br />
                                        <p>
                                            <span class="ContenidoContactoMensaje">Ingresa tu correo
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />

                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 alinearDerecha">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 row2">

                                            <input type="email" name="Contacto" id="Contacto" value="" size="50" class="form-control" />
                                            <div id="alert" class="alert alert-danger" style="font-family: 'Lettera Text Std';">Favor de ingresar una cuenta de correo válida.</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 row2">
                                            <button class="EnviarContactoDetalleProducto btn-lg" onclick="EnviarInformacion(1,1)"> Enviar</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
```

Comment: Esto parece no funcionar para mi, podemos validar con otro método la eliminación del `alert `

Comment: ¿@JohnDoe, a qué te refieres con que no funciona para ti? En el fragmento de código sí funciona.

Comment: Al ejecutarlo en mi código no funciona, se muestra el `alert` al momento de Enviar caracteres que no corresponda a un correo según la validación pero al escribir nuevamente no se oculta el `alert`

Comment: @JohnDoe, entonces debes editar tu pregunta para poner el código actual, solo así podemos tratar de ver lo que está fallando.

Comment: Agregue el código completo de la validación que publique en mi pregunta inicial, solo que en un comienzo no lo vi necesario, pido una disculpa.

Comment: @JohnDoe, con tu nuevo código sigue funcionando sin problema. Revisa la consola del navegador para ver si aparece algún error.

Comment: Revise mi consola cuando probé con tu respuesta pero no obtengo ningún warning o mensaje de error, existirá otra manera de borrar el `alert ` ya sea con un evento de teclado o similar ?

Comment: Funciono después de varios intentos, lo que hice fue introducir el evento `Input ` dentro la función `EnviarInformacion`, gracias por tu apoyo